# cover image por default css

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo un div que se arma por Javascript y un JSON, este pone una imagen que la trae de un servidor, el problema es que si la imagen no esta, el div se queda en blanco.

--UPDATE--

No tengo la URL en la base de datos, es armada de forma estàtica junto con el ID del elemento. No tengo acceso a la ruta, solo quiero comprobar si existe le pongo la foto, si no existe le pongo una por default

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++)
  {
        var precio = parseFloat(data.features[i].properties.precio);
        if (precio != '')
           precio = '$' + precio.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
         else
          precio = 'Sin precio';

        h += '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 propDetails"' +
        'style="background-image: url(\'ruta/images/'+ data.features[i].properties.id +'/foto_principal.jpg\')">' +
            '<img class="fav" src="../images/favorito.png">' +
              '<div class="details">' +
                  '<p class="dom"><span>'+ precio +'</span><br>'+ data.features[i].properties.calle +'</p>' +
              '</div>' +
        '</div>';
  }
```

Para poner esto por default intenté hacer esto en CSS

```
.propDetails
{
  background-image: url(../images/default.png);
}
```

No esta haciendo lo que trato de hacer
Que puedo implementar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Inspeccionaste el elemento y te fijaste la propiedad background-image de dicha div? Por que no generas el atributo src dinamicamente según si existe o no la imágen en vez de wrappearlo en otro div?

Comment: El problema, es que no se si existe la imagen o no, por que yo solo mando el ID de imagen, pero en realidad no se si exista. La imagen si tiene una URL, pero si copio esa URL al navegador, la foto no existe, el server me contesta que no se encontró el elemento.

Comment: Hola Alberto, deberías crear un [mcve] si es posible. Y aclarar un poco eso de que la imagen no existe o que no se encuentra: comparte el árbol de directorios de tu proyecto, dónde se ejecuta la página y dónde están (supuestamente) las imágenes. Si las imágenes no existen, poco podemos hacer. Aunque esto suena más a problemas de rutas.

Comment: Álvaro, si efectivamente, es un problema de rutas, la imagen no existe, únicamente quiero que si la imagen no existe, ponerle una por default.

Comment: Ok Alberto. Entonces es más fácil de lo que parece. Te escribo una respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En CSS puedes definir más de una imagen de fondo en `background-image` separadas por comas. Algo com esto, la primera imagen de la lista es la que aparecerá al frente, y si falla la última se mostrará:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(url-que-no-existe),
                    url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/cats);
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Entonces en tu código lo que tienes que hacer es añadir una imagen por defecto al final de la lista de `background-image` tal que así:

```
h += '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 propDetails"' +
    'style="background-image: url(\'ruta/images/'+ data.features[i].properties.id +'/foto_principal.jpg\'), url(../images/default.png)">' +
        '<img class="fav" src="../images/favorito.png">' +
          '<div class="details">' +
              '<p class="dom"><span>'+ precio +'</span><br>'+ data.features[i].properties.calle +'</p>' +
          '</div>' +
    '</div>';
```

Comment: Gracias Álvaro, justo lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes verificar si `data.features[i].properties.id` no esta vació o undefined y así unificar la url y después armar el div con la url validada, intenta esto:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++){
                var precio = parseFloat(data.features[i].properties.precio);
                if (precio != '') {
                    precio = '$' + precio.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
                } else {
                    precio = 'Sin precio';                              
                }
                if (data.features[i].properties.id != "") { 
                    var urlImage = data.features[i].properties.id +'/foto_principal.jpg';
                } else {
                    var urlImage = 'default.png';
                }
                h += '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 propDetails"' +
                'style="background-image: url(ruta/images/'+ urlImage + ')">' +
                '<img class="fav" src="../images/favorito.png">' +
                '<div class="details">' +
                '<p class="dom"><span>'+ precio +'</span><br>'+ data.features[i].properties.calle +'</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            }
```

Espero te sirva.